# jquery woes , image replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently creating a project, in which a user can click on thumbnail of an image, clicking on  the thumbnail, replaces the src of a main image, to show a bigger version of the thumbnail.

```
$('.alternative_images a').click(function(e){
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.mainImage').attr('src', imgSrc);
    $('#image').attr('href', imgSrc);
    $('#image').attr('rel', $(this).attr('title'));

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This works fine, I have also implemented jqZoom, however looking at a zoomed image, by hovering of the bigger image on the page, always shows the same image, regardless of whether you changed the image, by click on a thumbnails

The page in question is http://mensclothingroom.factoryagency.co.uk/product/ben-fogle-collection-expedition-sock/

Comment: There seems problem in your plugin. The image in your "zoomWrapperImage" div is not being replaced. Check how you are sending the image to the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to replace the entire element instead of just replacing the `src` attribute:

```
$('.mainImage').replaceWith('<img src="'+imgSrc+'" class="mainImage">');
```